# How can I have a users role change when they enter a pass code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passwords, cancan, roles

I have a table of users where each has a role (provided by the cancan gem). All new users are given the role of author.

I would like to be able to issue a sort of voucher code to certain users which when entered will change their role from author to admin.

Is there a way of doing this?

All the roles are already set up and can be changed by an existing admin by editing the users profile.

Thanks very much for any help its much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea:

Generate a token for each user in the system and store it in the database. Make a form where user can submit his code. Then, in a controller, you may add role you want, if the code supplied by user corresponds to the one written in the database.